# Why can't the compiler infer type parameter for package object (while it works fine for object)?

Tags: scala, polymorphism

Scala 2.11.4

**Foo.scala**

```
trait Echo [T] {
  def echo(t: T): Unit
}

trait IntEcho extends Echo[Int] {
  def echo(t: Int) = println(t)
}

object echo extends IntEcho
package object echo1  extends IntEcho
```

After I compile that file and load it to scala repl, I did following test

```
scala> :t echo.echo _ Int => Unit

scala> :t echo1.echo _ T => Unit
```

Why is T not resolved to Int?

Comment: Could be a REPL issue

Comment: Not only repl, not work while compiling

Comment: What is the version of your Scala

Comment: @Venki  scala 2.11.4 for my case

Comment: I am using 2.11.4 and I get `scala> :t echo.echo _
Int => Unit

scala> :t echo1.echo _
Int => Unit
`

Comment: @Jatin You may try compile this file https://gist.github.com/jilen/f0865b7402390b657aff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug see this [issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9074)  for detail